# Tag Manager Client API: Unable to access Tag Manager content with API key

Tags: google-api, google-tag-manager, google-authentication

I would like to connect to the Tag Manager Client API to access some content in a container without having to log in.

[This page](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/workspaces/variables/get?apix_params=%7B%22path%22%3A%22accounts%2F4701180995%2Fcontainers%2F11017286%2Fworkspaces%2F1%2Fvariables%2F1%22%7D#try-it) mentions at the top that it "Requires authorization". However, I am using the contents of a container to store ad urls and the users of the website I'm working on shouldn't be asked to log in to Google for this.

What also makes me confused is that the ["Try this API"](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/workspaces/variables/get#try-it) UI let's me choose Credentials using:

- Google OAuth 2.0
- or API key

However, when I select "API key", I get a 401 error with the message: "Login Required".

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "test this API" interface presents you with a choice that is not actually applicable.

The [API documentation for the GTM API](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/authorization) is quite unambiguous:

> Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other
>   authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google
>   Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

So the problem seems to be that the "try this API" has a generic UI that gives you options that are not actually valid for each of the APIs where it shows up.